# Azure Application Gateway, Azure App Service and Form Based Authentication

Tags: azure

I'm migrating a complete infrastructure over to Azure; it's been slow going as there's so much to learn and for every two steps forward, there seems to be one step back.

After what seems like an eternity, I think I've got it all sorted with one exception.

The architecture is as follows:
Azure Traffic Manager ==> 2 Azure Application Gateways (geo separated) ==> Azure App Service

A custom domain is used for the traffic manager and the gateways are listening for the same domain and, when the route matches, passing on the requests down to the app service.

The actual app itself is a ASP.NET MVC application and it uses forms authentication; and this is where the challenge happens.

When navigating to the public address: client.domain.com and hitting the website, it determines that the user is not authenticated and sends the browser to the login page...  so far so good but, rather than using client.domain.com/login it uses the web-server dns name, so client.azurewebsites.com/login

How do I go about changing the behaviour so that it uses the external DNS name rather than the website name?

I can't setup custom domains on the app service as the only route into the site is via the gateway as this is also the firewall.

Is there some Web Config setting I can make?  I'm looking at the outbound rewrite rules but these seem to only work on tags rather than 302 redirects.

Any thoughts would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup custom dns names on your webapp (you can use TXT record to verify dns name, so i dont see a reason why you can add it to the webapp). or you can alter the code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment however - that would work if it wasn't sitting under the application gateway. This is acting as a firewall and has the DNS records pointing to it; no traffic can directly access the web app as it can only go via the gateway.  Due to this, the same DNS record would need to be configured for both the gateway and the webapp.  It seems that altering the code is the only way :(

Comment: this makes no sense. this is perfectly possible

Comment: Thanks for your comment but, unfortunately it's not very helpful.  I'm sure it is possible but with the app gateway in place, the TXT/CNAME record would be pointing to the app gateway, not the web app.  This would be made inaccessible by a firewall rule so as to prevent direct access to the site.  With this, the DNS entry pointing to the web app would be pointless.

Comment: a records points to app gateway, txt record is used to verify the custom dns name. where is the problem? and you dont even need to keep it. verify it and you can delete txt record. why would you point TXT record to app gw???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: That's the key bit I think - add the record and then delete it.  I didn't realise that there was no need to keep the value there.  When adding a custom domain name, it gives the suggestion (or is this an instruction) to add an A record to the public IP address of the site and then the txt record pointing to the azurewebsites domain.  If these can be added and then removed, it makes things more understandable.  Chers

Comment: it doesnt matter. txt record is not used to route traffic

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem, I had to make a code change to the web app itself.  Not ideal but it worked.

What I had to do was to extend the code that redirects an unauthenticated request to the login page by sniffing for the X-Original-Host HTTP Header that the App Gateway forwards on.  This contains the public facing DNS name.  If the header is present and it is on a pre-approved white-list (so as to prevent any hijacking), then redirect the user to the login page for this domain, rather than the one the server is listening on directly (so use client.domain.com rather than client.azurewebsites.com)